# tex4ht: how to make only non-inline math bigger?

Tags: math-mode, equations, tex4ht, htlatex

I'm converting a document to html (or possibly xhtml) using htlatex. I find that the output is ok, but the equations are too small. I have tried making them bigger by adding the following to my configuration file:

```
\DeclareMathSizes{10}{24.88}{20.74}{17.28}
```

This successfully makes math bigger, but for both equaton environments and inline math expressions, which therefore no longer look good with the text. How can I make only non-inline math bigger in the output from htlatex?

I also prefer this to be done using a method easily portable and not requiring local configuration changes to my tex installation, as I move from computer to computer and also expect multiple people to work on the document.

Comment: I think you are going about this the wrong way. A much better way to do all of this, is to use mathml and not default images for math, and then use mathjax to render the math. See this http://www.mathjax.org/demos/scaling-math/ about how mathjax scales math. What this means is that you do not need to use `\DeclareMathSize` at all. Just configure tex4ht to use mathml and mathjax will be a better solution than having to deal with sizing math images.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This approach does not give arbitrary control over the size of display math, but allows it to be set larger, based on the built-in LaTeX size macros, such as `\Huge`.  The good news is that it should be portable.

```
\documentclass{article}
\let\svequation\equation
\def\equation{\Huge\svequation}
\let\svdisplaystyle\[
\let\svenddisplaystyle\]
\def\[{\Huge\svdisplaystyle}
\def\]{\svenddisplaystyle\normalsize}
\begin{document}
This is a $w = xyz_1$ inline test
\begin{equation}
w = xyz_1
\end{equation}
and now without the equation environment
\[
w = xyz_1
\]
xyz
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: This worked thanks, for others info, I put it in my tex4ht configuration file between `\Preamble{xhtml}` and `\begin{document}`